# Httplib can't handle a specific domain

Tags: python, http, exception, dns

I have a script which get HTTP Header of a lot of pages on Internet with `httplib` in Python.

My problem is on a [specific domain](http://iswtc.la) (and probably others), `httplib` raise an exception, and I don't understand why.

```
>>> import httplib
>>> http = httplib.HTTPConnection('iswtc.la')
>>> http.request('GET', '/a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 914, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 951, in _send_request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 908, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 780, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 739, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 720, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

What is different on this specific domain, and how can I handle this ?

PS : It's not really my code because this works fine :

```
>>> http = httplib.HTTPConnection('bit.ly')
>>> http.request('GET', '/a')
```

Comment: Well, if that works fine it is your code because it does not work...

Comment: @IanCarroll What do you mean ? I put this code in my `python` console, and I have no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bit.ly` exists, whereas `iswtc.la` doesn't:

```
$ nslookup bit.ly

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   bit.ly
Address: 69.58.188.39
Name:   bit.ly
Address: 69.58.188.40


$ nslookup iswtc.la

** server can't find iswtc.la: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: Right. I feel dumb right now. I was so concentrated on my code, that I forgot to check that the domain exists... Let's handle this exception.